# Program Hangs when reading UART RX buffer from a GPS Module

Tags: c, gps, microcontroller, uart, pic

This is on a custom PCB I designed for my capstone project and I've still been stumped on this as unfortunately I haven't had a lot of experience with UART. Which I'm sure is the issue, I've only found discussions mostly around arduino users etc, and not C programming/UART communications.

My program makes it into and reads the U3STAbits.URXDA true (buffer full), but it does not continue past that point and does not go to the line after trying to read U3RXREG.

I am using a PIC24FJ512GA606 Microcontroller and MPLAB X IDE, I don't have any peripheral libraries.

The GPS module I am trying to communicate to is Antenova M20048, Standby pin is brought high when I enable UARTEN under the mode register.

So far I've gotten zero response from my module I don't have means to probe it at home to see if its actually responding, the fact the buffer is being flagged as full gives me hope its all working and maybe I'm just missing something, if anyone has any ideas.

```
#define FCY 8000000    //required for __delay_us(time) function
#include "elen116header.h"
#include <libpic30.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>



int main(void)
{

    UART2_Initialize();
    UART3_Initialize();
   __delay_ms(250);
   __delay_ms(250);
   printf("LoRa Tranciever Unit Online\n") ;
   
   char c='0'; //declare a character
   char data[80] = {'\0'};  //declare a character array to store an entire message
   int count = 80; //declare an integer to be used as an index variable
   
  __delay_ms(250);
  __delay_ms(250);
  
   //transmit the command to GPS
   strcpy(data,"$PMTK414*33\r\n");
   printf(" Sending: ");
   int i;
   count = 80;
   for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
   {
       c = data[i];
       
       if(c == '\0' )
       {
           memset(data, '\0', sizeof(char) * 80);//clear data
           i = count;
       }
       else
       {
           UART3_Write(c);
           printf("%c", c);
       }
   }
   printf("\n\n Reading: ");
    
//transmission of command is finished, now read in characters
while(1) //forever read in and store the last NMEA message
{
        if(U3STAbits.OERR) //check to see if there's an overrun error
            U3STAbits.OERR = 0;//clear to allow messages to be received
        if(U3STAbits.URXDA) //check if data is ready to be read
        {
        printf("read attempt ");
        c = U3RXREG; //get a character from the receive buffer
        printf("%c", c);
        while(!(U3STAbits.URXDA == 1));
     if(c == '$') //c == $, hex=0x0024
        {
        count = 0; //for indexing the character array
        }
     if(count < 80)
        {
        data[count] = c;//store the character into the data array
        count++; //increment the index
        }
    }
}

   return 0;
}
```

And the header which has some configuration bits and UART configuration.

```
// PIC24FJ512GA606 Configuration Bit Settings

// 'C' source line config statements

// FSEC
#pragma config BWRP = OFF               // Boot Segment Write-Protect bit (Boot Segment may be written)
#pragma config BSS = DISABLED           // Boot Segment Code-Protect Level bits (No Protection (other than BWRP))
#pragma config BSEN = OFF               // Boot Segment Control bit (No Boot Segment)
#pragma config GWRP = OFF               // General Segment Write-Protect bit (General Segment may be written)
#pragma config GSS = DISABLED           // General Segment Code-Protect Level bits (No Protection (other than GWRP))
#pragma config CWRP = OFF               // Configuration Segment Write-Protect bit (Configuration Segment may be written)
#pragma config CSS = DISABLED           // Configuration Segment Code-Protect Level bits (No Protection (other than CWRP))
#pragma config AIVTDIS = OFF            // Alternate Interrupt Vector Table bit (Disabled AIVT)

// FBSLIM
#pragma config BSLIM = 0x1FFF           // Boot Segment Flash Page Address Limit bits (Boot Segment Flash page address  limit)

// FSIGN

// FOSCSEL
#pragma config FNOSC = FRC              // Oscillator Source Selection (Internal Fast RC (FRC))
#pragma config PLLMODE = DISABLED       // PLL Mode Selection (No PLL used; PLLEN bit is not available)
#pragma config IESO = ON                // Two-speed Oscillator Start-up Enable bit (Start up device with FRC, then switch to user-selected oscillator source)

// FOSC
#pragma config POSCMD = NONE            // Primary Oscillator Mode Select bits (Primary Oscillator disabled)
#pragma config OSCIOFCN = OFF           // OSC2 Pin Function bit (OSC2 is clock output)
#pragma config SOSCSEL = ON             // SOSC Power Selection Configuration bits (SOSC is used in crystal (SOSCI/SOSCO) mode)
#pragma config PLLSS = PLL_PRI          // PLL Secondary Selection Configuration bit (PLL is fed by the Primary oscillator)
#pragma config IOL1WAY = OFF             // Peripheral pin select configuration bit (Allow only one reconfiguration)
#pragma config FCKSM = CSDCMD           // Clock Switching Mode bits (Both Clock switching and Fail-safe Clock Monitor are disabled)

// FWDT
#pragma config WDTPS = PS32768          // Watchdog Timer Postscaler bits (1:32,768)
#pragma config FWPSA = PR128            // Watchdog Timer Prescaler bit (1:128)
#pragma config FWDTEN = OFF              // Watchdog Timer Enable bits (WDT Enabled)
#pragma config WINDIS = OFF             // Watchdog Timer Window Enable bit (Watchdog Timer in Non-Window mode)
#pragma config WDTWIN = WIN25           // Watchdog Timer Window Select bits (WDT Window is 25% of WDT period)
#pragma config WDTCMX = WDTCLK          // WDT MUX Source Select bits (WDT clock source is determined by the WDTCLK Configuration bits)
#pragma config WDTCLK = LPRC            // WDT Clock Source Select bits (WDT uses LPRC)

// FPOR
#pragma config BOREN = ON               // Brown Out Enable bit (Brown Out Enable Bit)
#pragma config LPCFG = OFF              // Low power regulator control (No Retention Sleep)
#pragma config DNVPEN = ENABLE          // Downside Voltage Protection Enable bit (Downside protection enabled using ZPBOR when BOR is inactive)

// FICD
#pragma config ICS = PGD2               // ICD Communication Channel Select bits (Communicate on PGEC1 and PGED1)
#pragma config JTAGEN = OFF             // JTAG Enable bit (JTAG is disabled)
#pragma config BTSWP = OFF              // BOOTSWP Disable (BOOTSWP instruction disabled)

// FDEVOPT1
#pragma config ALTCMPI = DISABLE        // Alternate Comparator Input Enable bit (C1INC, C2INC, and C3INC are on their standard pin locations)
#pragma config TMPRPIN = OFF            // Tamper Pin Enable bit (TMPRN pin function is disabled)
#pragma config SOSCHP = ON              // SOSC High Power Enable bit (valid only when SOSCSEL = 1 (Enable SOSC high power mode (default))
#pragma config ALTVREF = ALTREFEN       // Alternate Voltage Reference Location Enable bit (VREF+ and CVREF+ on RA10, VREF- and CVREF- on RA9)

// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.

/************************* DO NOT Alter any of the above code *******/
/************************* START of Your Program *********************/

            /***** Directives and Define AREA************/
#include <xc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
           

///////////////////////////////////////
// UART2
///////////////////////////////////////

void UART2_Initialize(void)
{
    
    /****************************************************************************
     * Set the PPS
     ***************************************************************************/
    __builtin_write_OSCCONL(OSCCON & 0xbf); // unlock PPS

    RPOR11bits.RP23R = 0x0005;    //RP23/RD1->UART2:U2TX
    RPINR19bits.U2RXR = 0x0018;    //RP24/RD2->UART2:U2RX

    __builtin_write_OSCCONL(OSCCON | 0x40); // lock PPS
    
/**    
     Set the UART2 module to the options selected in the user interface.
     Make sure to set LAT bit corresponding to TxPin as high before UART initialization
*/
    // STSEL 1; IREN disabled; PDSEL 8N; UARTEN enabled; RTSMD disabled; USIDL disabled; WAKE disabled; ABAUD disabled; LPBACK disabled; BRGH enabled; URXINV disabled; UEN TX_RX; 
    // Data Bits = 8; Parity = None; Stop Bits = 1;
    U2MODE = (0x8008 & ~(1<<15));  // disabling UARTEN bit
    // UTXISEL0 TX_ONE_CHAR; UTXINV disabled; URXEN disabled; OERR NO_ERROR_cleared; URXISEL RX_ONE_CHAR; UTXBRK COMPLETED; UTXEN disabled; ADDEN disabled; 
    U2STA = 0x00;
    // BaudRate = 9600; Frequency = 8000000 Hz; U2BRG 0x67; 
    U2BRG = 0x67;//0x33;
    // BaudRate = 57600; Frequency = 8000000 Hz; U2BRG 0x16; 
    //U2BRG = 0x16;//0x33;
    // BaudRate = 115200; Frequency = 8000000 Hz; U2BRG 0x16; 
    //U2BRG = 0x07;//0x33;
    
    // ADMADDR 0; ADMMASK 0; 
    U2ADMD = 0x00;
    
    UART2_Enable();  // enabling UARTEN bit
}

uint8_t UART2_Read(void)
{
    while(!(U2STAbits.URXDA == 1))
    {
        
    }

    if ((U2STAbits.OERR == 1))
    {
        U2STAbits.OERR = 0;
    }
    
    return U2RXREG;
}

void UART2_Write(uint8_t txData)
{
    while(U2STAbits.UTXBF == 1)
    {
        
    }

    U2TXREG = txData;    // Write the data byte to the USART.
}

uint16_t UART2_StatusGet (void)
{
    return U2STA;
}

void UART2_Enable(void)
{
    U2MODEbits.UARTEN = 1;
    U2STAbits.UTXEN = 1;
}

void UART2_Disable(void)
{
    U2MODEbits.UARTEN = 0;
    U2STAbits.UTXEN = 0;
}

///////////////////////////////////////
// UART3
///////////////////////////////////////


void UART3_Initialize(void)
{
    
    /****************************************************************************
     * Set the PPS
     ***************************************************************************/
    __builtin_write_OSCCONL(OSCCON & 0xbf); // unlock PPS

    RPOR4bits.RP9R = 0x0013;    //RP9/RB9>UART3:U3TX
    RPINR17bits.U3RXR = 0x0008;    //RP8/RB8->UART3:U3RX

    __builtin_write_OSCCONL(OSCCON | 0x40); // lock PPS
    ANSBbits.ANSB10 = 0;
    TRISBbits.TRISB10 = 0;
/**    
     Set the UART3 module to the options selected in the user interface.
     Make sure to set LAT bit corresponding to TxPin as high before UART initialization
*/
    // STSEL 1; IREN disabled; PDSEL 8N; UARTEN enabled; RTSMD disabled; USIDL disabled; WAKE disabled; ABAUD disabled; LPBACK disabled; BRGH disabled; URXINV disabled; UEN TX_RX; 
    // Data Bits = 8; Parity = None; Stop Bits = 1;
    U3MODE =  (0x8000 & ~(1 << 15));  // disabling UARTEN bit //
 
    // UTXISEL0 TX_ONE_CHAR; UTXINV disabled; URXEN disabled; OERR NO_ERROR_cleared; URXISEL RX_ONE_CHAR; UTXBRK COMPLETED; UTXEN disabled; ADDEN disabled; 
    U3STA = 0x00;
    // BaudRate = 9600; Frequency = 8000000 Hz; U2BRG 25; 
    U3BRG = 25;//0x33;
    // BaudRate = 57600; Frequency = 8000000 Hz; U2BRG 0x16; 
    //U3BRG = 0x16;//0x33;
    // BaudRate = 115200; Frequency = 8000000 Hz; U2BRG 0x16; 
    //U3BRG = 0x07;//0x33;
    
    // ADMADDR 0; ADMMASK 0; 
    U3ADMD = 0x00;
    
    UART3_Enable();  // enabling UARTEN bit
}

uint8_t UART3_Read(void)
{
   // while(!(U3STAbits.URXDA == 1)) //These are used in the program instead
    //{}

  //  if ((U3STAbits.OERR == 1))
   // {
   //     U3STAbits.OERR = 0;
   // }
    
    return U3RXREG;
}

void UART3_Write(uint8_t txData)
{
    while(U3STAbits.UTXBF == 1)
    {
        
    }

    U3TXREG = txData;    // Write the data byte to the USART.
}

uint16_t UART3_StatusGet (void)
{
    return U3STA;
}

void UART3_Enable(void)
{
    U3MODEbits.UARTEN = 1;
    U3STAbits.UTXEN = 1;
    U3STAbits.URXEN = 1;
    PORTBbits.RB10 = 1; //disable standby
}

void UART3_Disable(void)
{
    U3MODEbits.UARTEN = 0;
    U3STAbits.UTXEN = 0;
    U3STAbits.URXEN = 0;
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//helper function for std output functions

int __attribute__((__section__(".libc.write"))) write(int handle, void *buffer, unsigned int len) {
    int i;
    //UART2_Initialize();
    while(U2STAbits.TRMT == 0);  
    for (i = len; i; --i)
    {
        while(U2STAbits.TRMT == 0);
        U2TXREG = *(char*)buffer++;        
    }
    return(len);
}
//helper function for std intput functions
int __attribute__((__section__(".libc.read"))) read(int handle, void *buffer, unsigned int len) {
    int i;
    //UART2_Initialize();
    while(U2STAbits.URXDA == 0);  
    for (i = len; i; --i)
    {
        while(U2STAbits.URXDA == 0);
        *(char*)buffer++=U2RXREG;        
    }
    return(len);
}
```

Comment: If you don' receive anything, you must esure first the responder device is sending data, if it's ok then you must ensure that the baudrates of communicating devices is matching. Also you must check your wire connections. If the above cases are ok then we can look for the cause of your case in the code.

Comment: @Kozmotronik I'm assuming only way to do this would be actually probing it I can try that when I go to the lab on monday but unfortunately times up on my project by that point.  Am pretty sure all rest you've mentioned is fine and bauds are matching really wish I had a scope at home right now!